# WinForm Key Up event SHIFT and char

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to process an alphabetic character and underscores. How do I tell what char is typed if a SHIFT is also pressed. Currently, shifted chars are handled by  the ELSE clause.

```
private void txtSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (((int)e.KeyData >= 65 && (int)e.KeyData <= 122) ||
             (e.KeyData.ToString() == "_"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyData);
        //char thisChar = char excluding SHIFT, Control
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Process " + thisChar);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Throw away a " + e.KeyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use KeyDown/Up to reliably detect typing keys.  You only get virtual keys, the actual character they produce is heavily dependent on the keyboard layout.  Use the KeyPress event instead.  The intent of the code is not clear to give proper advice.

Comment: I am trying to implement an AutoComplete TextBox that goes to the database for a list of pick values. When I pl ace the code in the KeyPress event, the autocomplete drop down does not appear. I am multithreading, too. The intent is to search for database object names. My other issue is that the darn Autocomplete appears case sensitive. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Shift && (((int)e.KeyData >= 65 && (int)e.KeyData <= 122) || (e.KeyData.ToString() == "_")))
{
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

I took a slight different approach:

```
    private void txtSearch_KeyUp(object Sender, KeyEventArgs E)
    {
        int iKeyData = (int)(E.KeyData);

        if (((E.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.OemMinus) == true) && (E.Shift == true)) || ((iKeyData >= 65) && (iKeyData <= 122)))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(E.KeyData);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Throw away a " + E.KeyData);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how this will work with different keyboard layouts though - might want to look into that too.

Cheers!